# Can I do anything with a pre-wired photo resistor and no additional A/D converter?

Tags: analog-to-digital

So I have this SunFounder Photo Resistor module: https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/sensor-kit-v2-0-for-raspberry-pi-b-plus/lesson-20-photoresistor-module-sensor-kit-v2-0-for-b-plus.html

[image]

Until five minutes ago I didn't realise the RaspPi doesn't come with any sort of A/D converter capability whatsoever. So that lesson page assumes I have a separate A/D converter module (PCF8591).

Now I see this Adafruit tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/basic-resistor-sensor-reading-on-raspberry-pi/basic-photocell-reading - I tried simply connecting my module and running the python example, but it just hangs while trying to integrate the GPIO input.

My question is: **Can I use the module with an approach similar to the Adafruit tutorial to sample a light intensity reading?**

Comment: Here's an answer describing an alternative approach (without an ADC): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109446/33476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - with that module you need to use an ADC.

If you have a LDR (Light Dependent Resistor) and a suitable capacitor you could use the standard charge/discharge timing technique to estimate the resistance (and thus the light level).

E.g. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Hardware_ex_LDR

Answer (score 3):

I won't claim this is a very complete answer, but here goes:

> I tried simply connecting my module...

The **capacitor** in that Adafruit demo plays a vital role; it's what creates a fluctuating high/low signal which can be read as a digital frequency ([see here](https://learn.adafruit.com/basic-resistor-sensor-reading-on-raspberry-pi/how-it-works)).  Without that, the corresponding code will not be good for much.

> Can I use the module with an approach similar

Probably yes -- *with a capacitor.*

Without a capacitor, you might be able to get the photoresistor to register a change from very bright to very dark, if it can offer up enough change in resistance to make the difference between a "high" and "low" signal.

Attach a GPIO as an output to VCC set to high,<sup>1</sup> and another one to SIG as an input, and of course, a ground to GND.  Cover the resistor and check the state of the input, then try shining a very bright light on it and check again.  You don't need/can't use the Adafruit code for this since again, that is not the principle it works upon.

I have no idea if that will work but it is simple enough to try and should not damage anything.

---

<sup>1. You could probably also use a 3.3V power pin, although I *think* the GPIO is safer.</sup>