# Falling Marble Sensor

Tags: pi-zero, games

I'm trying to essentially build a Raspberry Pi powered pachinko machine, where I need to detect when a magnetic marble falls through a gate/opening/region.  Are there any electrical components/breakout boards/ideas I could use to detect such an occurrence?  I've been debating on using a Hall Effect Ratiometric sensor paired with an ADC converter and GPIO ports to detect magnetic fluctuation to detect when the marble passes, but I didn't know if there were any better ideas.  Maybe some sort of gate that won't mess with the marble's trajectory?  A light or motion sensor?  Something that can quickly detect the marble's presence?

For reference, [here are the magnetic marbles that I'm using](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L5WAIQC).  I'm using a Pi Zero too.

Comment: those magnetic marbles may be too brittle for your application .... also, what material are you planning to use for the pins?

Comment: Hmm do you think those marbles will shatter?  I actually won't be using any pins :)  I'm really building a sort of Rube Goldberg machine that students will assemble in order to guide a falling ball down through a series of gates/openings, where I need to detect when they're successful in making it through one of the gates.

Comment: I'm wondering if the phototransistor setup here might work well for this...  my only worry would be if the phototransistor would detect a ball moving very quickly.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xQcbjkGq0A

Comment: the marbles may shatter if dropped on the floor or if banged together

Comment: I've been trying to run a few experiments :) I just thought it wise to ask the hive mind if there were any simple ideas that I might not have thought of.

Comment: the arrangement in the video is a slot sensor .... the marble will not be too fast for it ... it may work with glass marbles also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [light sensor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51085/can-i-do-anything-with-a-pre-wired-photo-resistor-and-no-additional-a-d-converte) usually works pretty well when you can illuminate it with a LED and make sure that the passing marble will block that light.

[image]

You only [need](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109446/33476) an ADC / comparator when you want to measure / detect a very specific illumination level. If you instead can make sure there's enough illumination difference to toggle between 0 and 1, you can connect it directly to a digital pin.

Comment: I like this idea, and I see a few other people who have used similar solutions.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the size of the region through which the marbles pass.

If a Hall effect sensor can be positioned so that a marble always passes within a millimeter or so then it would seem a natural solution.  No need for an ADC.  The ones I have (OH3144E) default to Vcc and pull to ground when a magnet is close.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, I haven't nailed down the exact dimensions, though the gap is planned to be around 3 inches wide.  Sounds like a Hall Effect sensor might not be my best bet then.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but I'm just a hobbyist with very limited experience using one type of Hall effect sensor.